# Is it possible for us to fetch xpath/rowspan of an element during execution in selenium?

Tags: html-table

I wanted to delete a particular row in a table in UI using the associate id... there is delete image for each row. My logic was
1)To find the associate id and get its xpath and then equalise the row value of the xpath with that of the delete image and click on the respective image.
2) To find the associate id and get its rowspan and then give the rowspan in the xpath of the delete image as shown below. (but i dono how to get the rowspan of it).
Kindly help on it.

WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(.,'EDUAR ALEX')]")); 
        if (elem == null)
            System.out.println("The text is not found on the page!");
        else {
            System.out.println("The text is present!!");
        }

```
    int rowCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(.,'EDUAR ALEX')]")).size();
    System.out.println(rowCount);


    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr["+rowCount+"]/td[6]/a[2]/img")).click();
```

Thanks in advance!!!

```
<tr class="borderLeft">
<td align="center" class="col2">389206</td>
<td align="center" class="col3">EDUAR ALEX</td>
<td align="center" class="col4">Administrator,GIT,Report</td>
<td align="center" class="col5">410561</td>
<td align="center" class="col6">Apr  7 2014 11:47AM</td>
<td align="center" id="389206" class="col12"><a class="Edit_User" title="edit"   id="edit"><img width="16" height="16" id="389206" class="EditClass" alt="pdf" title="Administrator,GIT,Report" src="../StyleSheet/Images/page_white_edit.png"> </a><a id="389206" title="delete" class="delete"><img width="16" height="16" id="389206" class="DeleteClass" alt="Edit" src="../StyleSheet/Images/delete.png"></a></td></tr>

<tr class="altRow">
<td class="col2" align="center">360396</td>
<td class="col3" align="center">BERNIC JIM</td>
<td class="col4" align="center">Report</td>
<td class="col5" align="center">360396</td>
<td class="col6" align="center">Apr 11 2014  6:50PM</td>
<td class="col12" align="center" id="360396"><a id="edit" title="edit"   class="Edit_User"><img src="../StyleSheet/Images/page_white_edit.png" width="16" height="16" title="Report" alt="pdf" class="EditClass" id="360396"> </a><a class="delete" title="delete" id="360396"><img src="../StyleSheet/Images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Edit" class="DeleteClass" id="360396"></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to delete particular row which has anchor and its successive sibling is image and you want to delete that row using that id of anchor tag can you please provide html code of any one of that row so that it would be more easier, I have done some think like it earlier using code like 
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@name='"+Name+"']["+(rowCount+1)+"]/succeeding-sibling::*")));
element.click();

Please post html

Comment: yeah.. i wanted to click on the delete button of a particular id, which i have to search in the page and then get its xpath and with that i have to delete the particular delete button of that id. Please find the code below

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

Iterator<WebElement> itr = links.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    String DataToDelete = itr.next().getText();

    if(DataToDelete.equals("EDUAR ALEX")){

        // you can find the xpath using this code but to reach and click  the desired delete image u can use below code

    String xpath = driver.findElement(By.name(DataToDelete)).getAttribute("xpath");

    //or below code uses id to reach the desired anchor tag and then it's succeeding sibling which is image in ur case and click on that image 

    String id = driver.findElement(By.name(DataToDelete)).getAttribute("id");
    List<WebElement> ElementID=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@id='"+id+"']"));
    Iterator<WebElement> anchoritr=ElementID.iterator();
    while(anchoritr.hasNext()){
                WebElement AllAtributes=anchoritr.next();

                String GetTitle=AllAtributes.getAttribute("title").toString(); 
               if(GetTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
                  WebElement delete=AllAtributes.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='"+id+"']/succeeding-sibling::*"));
                   delete.click();
                   }
               }
    }

}
```

Please let me know if it works or not.